# Why does my form open in a new Tab?

Tags: jsf

Here is my code:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Guess Number</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        The number I guessed is: #{guessNumber.generatedNumber}
        <br />        
        <strong>Please guess the number I generated which is between 0 and 10!</strong>
        <h:form target="index">          
            <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Guess The Number!"></h:commandButton>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

So in the output I see something like:

> The number I guessed is: 6  Please guess the number I generated which
>   is between 0 and 10!

and a button below this text. When I click the button, the page opens in a new tab. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's caused for the [`target`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp) attribute in the `<h:form>`. Note that this is defined for pure HTML, not a JSF-ish special behavior.

To solve the *problem*, just remove the `target` attribute from the `<h:form>`.

Comment: But when I click that button on the new tab, a new tab will not open. It will open in the same tab. It only opens a new tab in the first try.

Comment: That's because the new target is `index`. This will be the name of the window, so every time you will target the results to the `index` window (that was already created and it's your new window/tab). Again, this is HTML behavior, not related with JSF. To have a better understanding please refer to the link in the answer.